# Crazy behavior in jquery date-picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 different instances of the jquery date-picker from jquery1.8.1.min.js in my RoR application.

I have this function:

```
    $(".date-picker:not('#policy_starts_on')").datepicker();
    $('#policy_starts_on.date-picker').datepicker({
        startDate: '0',
        endDate: '+90d'
    });
```

Which goes with this input:

```
<input class="required  date-picker input-small align-center" id="policy_starts_on" name="policy[starts_on]" size="30" type="text" value="02/27/2013">
```

Then I have this function:

```
    $(".date-picker:not('#act_event_ends_on')").datepicker();
    $('#act_event_ends_on.date-picker').datepicker({
        startDate: '0',
        endDate: '+180d'
    });
```

Which goes with this input:

```
<input class="required date-picker input-small align-center" id="act_event_ends_on" name="act_event[ends_on]" size="30" type="text">
```

Both inputs are being generated by ruby form helpers:

This being the first form helper:

```
= f.input :starts_on, :label => 'Policy Start Date', :required => true
```

And this is the second form helper:

```
= f.input :ends_on, :label => 'Event End Date', :required => true
```

**Question:** Why is the first input being restricted properly (I.E. you can't pick a day in the past and it will only allow you to go 90 days into the future) while the second input is not being restricted at all?

---

Comment: why are you calling `.datepicker()` twice for both of them?

Comment: Another "Copy and paste fail" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$(".date-picker:not('#policy_starts_on')").datepicker();
```

initializes the second input (the one with id="act_event_ends_on"), because it has the `date-picker` class and does not have the `policy_starts_on` id.

As a result, this element has already been initialized and the following code will not do anything for you any more:

```
$('#act_event_ends_on.date-picker').datepicker({
    startDate: '0',
    endDate: '+180d'
});
```

SOLUTION:

My recommendation would be to give the exceptions special class names (i.e. "date-picker-special"):

```
<input class="required  date-picker date-picker-special input-small align-center" id="policy_starts_on" name="policy[starts_on]" size="30" type="text" value="02/27/2013">

<input class="required date-picker date-picker-special input-small align-center" id="act_event_ends_on" name="act_event[ends_on]" size="30" type="text">
```

Then you can do the following:

```
$(".date-picker:not('.date-picker-special')").datepicker();
$('#policy_starts_on.date-picker').datepicker({
    startDate: '0',
    endDate: '+90d'
});
$('#act_event_ends_on.date-picker').datepicker({
    startDate: '0',
    endDate: '+180d'
});
```

Comment: Added special class and it worked great, thanks for that. Yea I didn't write the original just inherited it with no explanation of what the `$(".date-picker:not(''))"` line was doing. But what you said makes sense. And now I know what it does for the future. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

just for the sake of experimentation, does the opposite behavior happen if you declare those datepicker setups in the opposite order? if the opposite one breaks, then you could conclude that datepicker has a bug (which is unlikely). otherwise, you'd need to look at your own code.

also, note that you've preceded each block with something like this:

```
$(".date-picker:not('#policy_starts_on')").datepicker();
```

which is saying to select ALL date pickers except that one particular one.

so next time you set one up, its already been spoken for. try removing those one-liners, and you are left with:

```
$('#policy_starts_on.date-picker').datepicker({
    startDate: '0',
    endDate: '+90d'
});

$('#act_event_ends_on.date-picker').datepicker({
    startDate: '0',
    endDate: '+180d'
});
```

Comment: +1 for same info, but other guy offered solution that got it working. Thanks for taking the time to look though.